# HashMap with date ranges

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I need to find some values **very fast** based on a multi-key.
The key is composed by:
    `< Int userId, String measureName, Date startDate, Date endDate >`
and the value is a double.

The problem is that I have to ask for the value indicating a day, and not a date range.
So if I'll ask for a `userId`, a `measureName` and a day, the data structure has to answer with the value where the day is between `startDate` and `endDate` (there are no overlap between date ranges).

I cannot understand which is the better data structure to implement this. HashMap? TreeMap? MultiKeyMap? RangeMap? Help! :)

Comment: How many entries are you likely to have for each user / measure combination?

Comment: If you think about smart metering/timeseries no of them. Find other solution. Similar to timeseries

Comment: not too many, let's say 100, the problem is that is asked a lot of time. (80k times for a function that is called quite often)

Comment: How large are the date ranges? Maybe simply create an entry for each date in the range. Its the old **memory vs. speed** decision.

Comment: Guava's [`RangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) ?

Comment: a function call (done quite often) should create an hundred objects with a date range of 2 year each. so 100 x 702.Maybe is starting to be too much? I will lose a lot of time just inserting them in the map

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use TreeMap and methods like:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry(K)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherEntry(K)
but use in comparison function only one date - startDate or endDate. As those ranges don't overlap this shouldn't be a problem and make mentioned methods from TreeMap usable.

For example: if you decide to use in comparison `endDate` (and other fields except other dates) than you should use method `floorEntry`

Comment: Although there is no overlap, there could be dates that are not within a start/end date range...

Comment: ... But you should only have to compare the endDate one time.

Comment: @jahroy Oh, I see; I misunderstood and thought the suggestion was to use the dates directly as the map key.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap with a custom key object would be best.  You'd have something like:

```
...
TreeMap<MyMultiKey,Double> map = ...

class MyMultiKey implements Comparable<MyMultiKey>{
...
}
```

Assuming `MyMultiKey`'s `compareTo` method was implemented to order your multi-keys properly, you could create a new `MyMultiKey` instance each time you wanted to search for a specific day by using `map.floorKey(MyMultiKey m)` and `map.higherKey(MyMultiKey m)` to make sure you found a key with a start and end time that contained the day you specified in your new key instance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend some Map for the User/Measurement partial key.
The value would be a sorted array of tuples (date range, floatval).
In this array you perform binary search for a date range that contains the day.

Answer (score 0):

What about a combination of `Map` and ordered `List`? The map has a compound key of `userId` and `measureName`, the value is a sorted list of date range and double `value`:

```
Map<Key,List<Entry>> data = new HashMap<>();
List<Entry> entries = data.get(new Key(userId, measureName));
int i = Collections.binarySearch(entries, new Entry(searchDate,searchDate, 0.0));
double value = i < 0 ? 0.0 : entries.get(i).value;
```

`Key` has to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` using its members `userId` and `measureName`. `Entry` has to implement `Comparable<Entry>` where `compareTo()` has to return 0 if one range is part of the other (startDate comparison is <= 0 and endDate comparison is >= 0 or 0 if startDate comparison is >= 0 and endDate comparison is <= 0) else compare startDate+(endDate-startDate)/2 (middle of the range) regardless of the double `value`.

If you mostly read and not modify this structure, it should be fast. The comparison will be compiled to native if used much. If the function works on a single user and measure only, you can use the sorted list only, if only on a single user, you may create a  `Map<UserId<Map<MeasureName,List<Entry>>>>` like structure instead.

Try a simple solution first, measure before and after, do performance optimizations only if needed.